# Клиент-сервер в Unity: Unity Transport 0.3.0

Tags: c#, .net, unity3d, клиент-сервер, unity3d-android

Погуглив, нашел package для мультиплеера в Unity: https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.transport@0.3/manual/workflow-client-server.html
Понимаю, как подключиться к известному мне ip-адресу сервера. Но что делать, если ip адрес сервера в локальной сети клиент не знает.

Выход, который у меня работает в консоли C#, но Unity его не принимает: получаю первые 3 цифры локального ip, допустим: 168.192.0.х, а далее асинхронно пингую в цикле от 2 до 254.

**Вопрос:** какой есть вариант обнаружения ip-адреса сервера?

Answer (score 0):

Простой способ это от клиента отправить broadcast message внутри сети по udp протоколу, а на сервере запущен, и всегда работает, прослушиватель такого рода сообщений, и если сообщение удовлетворяет серверным требованиям, то сервер отправит клиенту примерно таким же способом отправит свой ip-адрес. По чаще пользуйтесь поисковиком, в интернете куча различных решений на любую проблему или задачу.

[Ссылка на пример](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/870328/receiving-a-broadcast-message-in-c-sharp)

Comment: почему может быть такое, что с разных устройств не получается подключение? Для сервера я использую ваш пример, для клиента    
|
    
`clientSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
                SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
            clientSocket.Connect(IPAddress.Broadcast, 9050);
            byte[] data = new byte[1024];
            clientSocket.Send(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("HelloFromClient"));`
@nipercop